# Двойная сортировка в Map

Tags: java, concurrency

Добрый день. может кто подскажет, уже все перепробовал
Есть мапа
 `Map<List<String>, Integer> mapDistanceSort = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

Метод сортировки

```
        int index = mapDistance.size();
        CompareMapValue[] compareMapValues = new CompareMapValue[index];
        index = 0;
        for (HashMap.Entry<List<String>, String> entry : mapDistance.entrySet()) {
            compareMapValues[index++] = new CompareMapValue(entry.getKey(), Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue()));
        }
        Arrays.sort(compareMapValues);
        int keyNum = 0;
        for (CompareMapValue cmv : compareMapValues) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(String.valueOf(cmv.list));
            list.add(String.valueOf(cmv.i));
            mapDistanceSort.put(list, keyNum);
           // mapDistanceSort2.put(cmv.list, cmv.i);
            keyNum++;
        }
```

Сам компоматор

```
public class CompareMapValue implements Comparable {
public List<String> list;
public Integer i;

public CompareMapValue(List<String> list, Integer i) {
    this.list = list;
    this.i = i;
}

public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof CompareMapValue) {
        final int diff = i.intValue() - ((CompareMapValue) o).i.intValue();
        return diff < 0 ? -1 : (diff > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Например

```
[[Иванов, Иван, 0], 25]
[[Сидоров, Коля, 1], 15]
[[Иванов, Иван, 1], 25]
[[Кузним, Кузя, 0], 45]
[[Савелов, Сава, 1], 74]
```

Я сделал сортировку по значению, на выходе получил

```
[[Сидоров, Коля, 1], 15]
[[Иванов, Иван, 0], 25]
[[Иванов, Иван, 1], 25]
[[Кузним, Кузя, 0], 45]
[[Савелов, Сава, 1], 74]
```

Но мне надо еще ее отсортировать по третьему значению в массиве, то есть первые у кого 1, потом у кого 0.

В итоге получить вот так должен, то есть у меня 1 это признак приоритетности

```
[[Сидоров, Коля, 1], 15]
[[Иванов, Иван, 1], 25]
[[Савелов, Сава, 1], 74]
[[Иванов, Иван, 0], 25]
[[Кузним, Кузя, 0], 45]
```

Может есть какой-то способ отсортировать? Может как-то поместить в другую мапу, поменяв значения местами или еще как-то?
Состав Массива в мапе можно менять,можно записать во временную и тд, это не играет роли. Главное получить итоговую отсортированную по двум значениям, причем приоритетность важнее.

Пытаюсь вот так после первой сортировки, но берет только первые 2 значения

```
   Map<List<String>, Integer> n = new TreeMap<List<String>, Integer>(new Comparator<List<String>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
                String[] o3 = o1.get(0).split(", ");
                String[] o4 = o2.get(0).split(", ");
                return Integer.parseInt(o4[2].replace("]", "").trim()) - Integer.parseInt(o3[2].replace("]", "").trim());
            }

        });
        n.putAll(mapDistanceSort);
        System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться возможностями Java 8 Stream API и решить довольно просто:

```
Map<List<String>, Integer> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(
        Comparator.<Map.Entry<List<String>, Integer>, String>
            comparing(e -> e.getKey().get(2)).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
    ).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
    );
```

Сначала выполняем сортировку в обратном порядке по третьему значению из списка: `comparing(e -> e.getKey().get(2)).reversed()`, а затем - сортировку по значению: `thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)`.

PS: Здесь результат снова собирается в `Map` с помощью `collect`, однако после этого порядок снова не гарантируется. Лучше использовать непосредственно стрим, например, направив его на вывод:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(
        Comparator.<Map.Entry<List<String>, Integer>, String>
            comparing(e -> e.getKey().get(2)).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
    ).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
[Сидоров, Коля, 1]=15
[Иванов, Иван, 1]=25
[Савелов, Сава, 1]=74
[Иванов, Иван, 0]=25
[Кузним, Кузя, 0]=45
```

Comment: Вот я этот вариант изучал сейчас, не успел протестить.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш подход некорректный. Вы передаете лист в качестве ключа, отсюда вы получите огромное количество проблем. Фактически этот лист еще и типизирован Object либо в крайнем случае String, хотя в рельности там и строки и цифры. Мало того, очень сложно контролировать в какоми именно элементе листа что лежит. При этом не стоит забывать, что любая Map работает с хешкодом, а в Вашем случае это хешкод листа Object и такой же equels. Следующая проблема в том, что у Map всего 3 реализации , из которой HashMap вообще не гарантирует упорядоченности элементов, т.е. в ее пределах вы вообще ничего не можете отсортировать. LinkedHashMap хранит элементы в том порядке, в котором они туда отправились. Остатся только TreeMap, это как раз сортированная коллекция и работает она , как и все сортировки в коллекциях , на основе компоратора. Поэтому , если вам действительно нужен Map в этом случае, рекомендовал бы пользоваться последней, а ваших людей затолкнуть в специальный класс, где вы сможете контролировать вышеуказанные equels, hashCode, кроме того, сами переопределите метод compare для сортировки, а еще четко будете знать, какая переменная какое поле хранит.
Но лично я рекомендовал бы вам в данном случае вообще не использовать Map. Берите List либо Set для уникальных объектов. В последнем тоже есть TreeSet, работающий по тому же принципу, что и TreeMap, а для любого листа есть Collections.sort. Ваше значение в map я так понимаю, что это возраст, нужно сделать еще одним полем класса и всех делов. И тогда для любого листа вы можете написать неограниченное количество компараторов и пользоваться любым по выбору, сортируя эти данные как вам угодно.
Код выглядит примерно так.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Object> {    
    //for testing only
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map <Person,Integer> map = new TreeMap <> ();
        map.put(new Person("Иванов", "Иван", 0), 25);
        map.put(new Person("Сидоров", "Коля", 3), 15);
        map.put(new Person("Петров", "Петр", 1), 25);
        map.put(new Person("Кузним", "Кузя", 2), 45);
        map.put(new Person("Савелов", "Сава", 0), 74);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private int priority;    

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String surname, String name, int priority) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.surname);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 67 * hash + this.priority;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (this.priority != other.priority) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.surname, other.surname)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "surname=" + surname + ", name=" + name + ", priority=" + priority + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {   
        try {
            Person p = (Person) o;
            if (p.getPriority() == this.priority) {
                return p.hashCode()-this.hashCode();
            }
            if (p.getPriority() < this.priority) return -1;
            else return 1;
        } catch (NullPointerException | ClassCastException e) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Если все таки хотите костыль , то можно так

```
public static Map sortMap(Map<List<String>, Integer> mapDistanceSort) {
    Map<List<String>, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(mapDistanceSort.size());
    mapDistanceSort.forEach((k,v)->{if ("0".equals(k.get(2))) sortedMap.put(k, v);});
    mapDistanceSort.forEach((k,v)->{if ("1".equals(k.get(2))) sortedMap.put(k, v);});
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: Это никак не решает проблему автора сортировки сначала по значению, а потом приоритету.

Comment: сортировку по значению в любой из Map сделать в принципе невозможно. Загнать все значения в лист, отсортировать, а потом строить LinkedHashMap , исходя из этой сортировки, и подобные костылеобразные способы не рассматриваю в принципе, как полный идиотизм.

Comment: Ну то есть вы не станете решать бизнес задачу, потому что единственный способ, который вам приходит в голову это полный идиотизм по вашему?

Comment: Подробнее выложил код, тут задача такая, что данные берутся из Excel, далее я создаю мапу и загоняю в нее массив, как key и дистанцию, как валуе, но в массиве еще есть признак, и мне по признаку надо сортировать именно после того, как я отсортирую по дистанции. То есть, мне массив в данном случае проще, так как я дальше уже его разбираю. Я сейчас уже пытался сделать немного по другому, но у меня только первые 2 значения сортирует.

Comment: Нет, я предлагаю решать бизнесс-задачу прямыми руками. Но если вы можете отсортировать Map по значению, я очень рад за вас, хотя это тоже в данном случае ничего не решает

Comment: По значению я отсортировал, мне вот нужно теперь по key,но так как в key лежит массив, то нужно чтобы он сортировал по последнему элементу. но и главное, чтобы не сбилась сортировка по значению

Comment: владислав, ваш способ сводится не к сортировке Map, а к предварительной сортировке элементов с дальнейшим заталкиванием их в Map. Таким же чудо-способом вы можете к добавить любое условие сортировки, но это плохой способ. Попробуйте тот способ, о котором я говорю. Если у вас ничего не получится, хотя я уверен, что получится, я вам напишу сортировку вашей Map так , как вы хотите, хотя там ее просто придется еще раз пересоздавать.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня уже довольно объемная работа проделана, и сложно переделать в объект отдельный мой массив, так как он собирается тоже. И после сортировки будет разбираться и записываться снова в Excel. У меня логика в основном на Map построена, перезапись, удаление элементов и тд. Я сейчас попробую Stream API

Comment: Добавил в ответ простой метод, рабоает на костыле , но если подкинуть в него сортированную по значению Map, то на выходе получите Map с учетом своего приоритета

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, сортировка получилась. Мне такого костыля вполне достаточно.

Comment: Ну , смотрите сами... В какую сторону смотреть, когда утоните в костылях, я вам подсказал))

Comment: Я хотел поинтересоваться, чем лучше создавать объекты, за место одного массива и добавить в мапу? У меня в проекте много мап на самом деле, процесс состоит в постоянном переборе, перевертывание и удалении записей из мап, чтобы в итоге получить финальную, которая будет перенесена в эксель. Я бы рад без мап на самом деле. Я просто уже задумался, о переделывание алгоритма и кода. Сам я новичок, но уже сделал несколько сложных проектов. Дело в том, как я знаю, создания много объектов, ведет в переполнению памяти, а у меня не три персоны, а 100 и более

Comment: а вы считаете, что ваша коллекция, содержащая стринги, которая размещена в другой коллекции - это не объекты? завтра перекинем в чат обсуждение и попытаюсь объяснить

Comment: Я свой алгоритм попробую переделать, как вы говорите. Потому что я в любом случае создаю массив, либо StringBilder при формировании строки и добавляю в Map.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у вас не совсем правильная архитектура, если вам нужно сортировать по приоритету и значению, значит это ключи, соотвественно `Map'a` (или временная `Map'a) должна содержать объекты`Map`, где key это объект c полями priority и value, а Value со всеми остальными (естественно имена типов должны быть более подходящими). Тогда для сортировки можно использовать обычный`TreeMap`.

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант, не додумался до него. Но я буду алгоритм переделывать, как сказал выше Дмитрий. Просто у меня идет постоянное сравнение Имен из одной мапы с другой, если совпало, то добавляется в третью мапу и тд. Я посчитал, что вариант мапы + массивы хорошо подходят по такое. То есть у меня своего рода алгоритм перебора и распределения